# What is the type of the return value of a map function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js

It's my first time using typescript in a nextjs project.
Sorry about the silly question...

```
const allImagesData: [{ id: string; fullpath: string }] = fileNames.map(
  (fileName): { id: string; fullpath: string } => {
    const id = fileName;
    const fullpath = "/testimgs/" + fileName;

    return {
      id,
      fullpath,
    };
  }
);
```

`allImagesData: [{ id: string; fullpath: string }]` part is wrong.

error:

> Type '{ id: string; fullpath: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ id: string; fullpath: string; }]'.

Question:

What should it be?

Comment: `[{ id: string; fullpath: string }]` is a tuple. `{ id: string; fullpath: string }[]` is an array.

Comment: thanks, got it. it should be { id: string; fullpath: string }[]....